# Is Float really missing from HtmlTextWriterStyle?

Tags: .net

Is float really missing from HtmlTextWriterStyle?

I rarely use

```
Control.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Whatever, "myval");
```

to set styles for elements, but occasionally I have to create a dynamic element from code-behind and I'll throw in a style via this method, to test out some styling.

Today, I tried to set

```
float:left;
```

and was fairly stunned that it doesn't appear to have a float property.  I couldn't find much on Google except for this brief log of the issue: [Microsoft Connect Log of Error](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=110709).

So my question is this: Is it really missing and why?

**EDIT**

So I followed up with [@Thomas Levesque](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98713/thomas-levesque)'s answer and found that the [HtmlTextWriterStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmltextwriterstyle%28VS.71%29.aspx) enumeration was introduced on [April 3rd, 2003 in .Net 1.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#.NET_Framework_1.1).  This was a time when [IE 6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_6) was the latest and greatest that MS had to offer.  It is possible that due to their shoddy standards, they were still relying on table based layouts.

I don't have any proof that this is the **truth**, but it's my favorite answer so far.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can still use the other `Add` overload :

```
control.Style.Add("float", "left");
```

But indeed it's weird that it's not in the `HtmlTextWriterStyle` enumeration... probably because Internet Explorer wasn't able to render it correctly at the time this enumeration was created ;)

Comment: True and ideally, i should just use a CSS class defined in a stylesheet, but what I really want to know is why is such an important attribute missing from the HtmlTextWriterSTyle enumeration?

Comment: Ooo, I like that additional piece of info.  That may well be the answer :D